# The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold, SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am facing the error below, how to fix it?
This is office 365 SharePoint list which has more than five thousand items on it.
I am using U2U tool to get data :

[image]

any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Use filters in a way that it will return less than 5000 items.

Comment: I used already Status ='New', which will get less than 100 item!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the list item threshold by indexing the affected column, more information can be found here:

[Manage large lists and libraries](https://support.microsoft.com/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

Comment: all these has been applied and still getting the same issue

Comment: Is the column you're using for the query a supported column for indexing?

Comment: no but I need to filter by it

Comment: I'm guessing the column you're using is a multi-value choice column, rather than an ordinary single value choice column? Can't you use a column type which is supported by indexing? If not, there isn't much that can be done to help here.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

Comment: Yes, you were right, the status column was not index, after adding it as index it works.